# Setting Delete Key for Edit Text

Tags: android, android-edittext, listener

In my program I have an EditText that I set an `OnKeyListener` for. The problem is this seems to make it so the delete key no longer deletes text in the EditText. Can anyone tell me how to set the delete key so it deletes text from the EditText once again?

Below are the bare-bones of how I'm setting the `onKeyListener`:

```
searchEntryEditText.setOnKeyListener((onKeyListener = new OnKeyListener() {
                    @Override
                    if (event.getAction() != KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN      
                            & keyCode == 66) {
                        Globals.searchEntryString = searchEntryEditText
                                .getText().toString();
                }
            }));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a button and set keylisttner to clear the text field.

```
String s = Edittext.gettext().toSrting();
String newstring = s.subString(0, s.length -1);
Edittext.settext(newstring);
```

Comment: I need to be able to delete a single character from the end of the string in the EditText.

Comment: I change the answer refer it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your answer does yeild the desired behavior but it does not address the root problem I'm dealing with. The Edit text has an on key listener that is set on instantiation which tells it to delete characters when the delete key is pressed. What I really need is a way to add an onKeyListener with out erasing the Edit Text's default onKeyListener(). Because your answer did address the issue I'll give you a green check once I figure out how to resolve the previously stated issue.